# No SQL option on Export of a table in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

PHPMyAdmin is showing some strange results when I go to export a table as SQL. If I go to the main database and select Export (i.e. the whole database) at the top it works as expected but when I go to a table and try end export just that table, there is no SQL option in the select list on the "Format:" section.

[image]

I am using Server version: 5.5.62(MySQL) and phpmyadmin 4.8.4. This is server wide (happening on all db's on this server)

There is a workaround, I can go to the main database level and export all and only tick the options of the tables I want but want to get this to work.

I have read about a max_input_vars setting but if this was the case, it would not export the whole DB, this just happens at a table level.

Thanks in advance

Comment: **Fixed after 4.8.4 version, download latest version**.

Answer (score 10):

The fix does work, have applied it to many servers at this point.

[Fix # 14775](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/95114841420af6277b0406ec7f0d32c4ff3fcf27) : edit `'Export.php'`

**Resolution:**

Connect to the server via SSH.

Open file:

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/htdocs/domains/databases/phpMyAdmin/libraries/classes/Display/Export.php with a text editor.
```

Note: for Windows, it will be

```
%plesk_dir%admin\htdocs\domains\databases\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Display\Export.php.
```

Find line `/* Scan for plugins */`

Add the following above the line:

```
// Export a single table
if (isset($_GET['single_table'])) {
    $GLOBALS['single_table'] = $_GET['single_table'];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is caused by a bug in version 4.8.4 of phpmyadmin. ppmyadmin team are working on it in [this github issue](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14775).

There seems to a workaround available (I did not test it myself) : *if I select the db, then checkbox the table(s), exporting under "with selected" I get the SQL option*.

Comment: The latest version of the 4.8 code stream of phpMyAdmin has fixed the problem. From the [change log](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/files/4.8.5/).

Answer (score 2):

I am using xampp in ubuntu locally and I don't have **/usr/local/psa/admin/htdocs/domains/databases/phpMyAdmin/libraries/classes/Display/Export.php** file. SO I searched about this file and I found it here: **/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Display/Export.php**
After editing this file from the

```
// Export a single table
if (isset($_GET['single_table'])) {
$GLOBALS['single_table'] = $_GET['single_table'];
}
```

(as the first answer) resolved my problem.